# How do you use a php variable for directory path?

Tags: javascript, php, html, directory

I am getting userid from the url.
This is what I have at the moment. I want to replace the one with $userid but I don't know how. It doesn't work and I can't seem to find the right syntax, please can someone help?

```
function returnimages($dirname = "Photos/1")
```

Basically I am trying to create a photo slideshow using html, php and javascript. I had something working before I started adding php into my code. I had html and an external javascript that changes the photos and they fade in and out in a loop. I have a photo array in javascript. Right now I am trying to add php to my html. I want to be able to get userid via url and then from that get the photos from a specific path to the userid in the directory. Then I am hoping to create an array of these photos and use them in my javascript. Here is my php code embedded in my html:

```
<?php

$user_id = $_GET['userid'];
print " Hi,  $user_id ";

function returnimages($dirname = "Photos/1") {   //will replace 1 with userid once something starts working
$pattern="(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$)"; //valid image extensions
$files = array();
$curimage=0;
if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
if(eregi($pattern, $file)){ //if this file is a valid image
//Output it as a JavaScript array element
echo 'galleryarray['.$curimage.']="'.$file .'";';
$curimage++;
}
}

closedir($handle);
}
return($files);
}

echo 'var galleryarray=new Array();'; //Define array in JavaScript
returnimages() //Output the array elements containing the image file names

?>
```

And my javascript:

$ (document).ready(function(){

```
var photodisplay = 
[
$("#photo1"),
$("#photo2"),
$("#photo3"),
$("#photo4"),
$("#photo5"),
];

//photodisplay[0].hide().fadeIn(3000);

var user = new Array();
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// List of images for user one
/*var userphoto = new Array();
userphoto[0] = "Photos/1/1.jpg";
    userphoto[1] = "Photos/1/2.jpg";
        userphoto[2] = "Photos/1/1.jpg";
            userphoto[3] = "Photos/1/1.jpg";
                userphoto[4] = "Photos/1/1.jpg";*/


//preloading photos
var userphoto = <? echo json_encode($galleryarray); ?>;
function preloadingPhotos() {
for (var x=0; x<5; x++)
{
    photodisplay[x].attr("src", "Photos/1" + userphoto[x]);
    photodisplay[x].hide();
    console.log("preloaded photos");

}
displayPhoto();
}

function displayPhoto(){

    photodisplay[0].fadeIn(3000);
    photodisplay[0].delay(3000).fadeOut(3000, function() { //first callback func
    photodisplay[1].fadeIn(3000);
    photodisplay[1].delay(3000).fadeOut(3000, function() { //second callback func
    photodisplay[2].fadeIn(3000);
    photodisplay[2].delay(3000).fadeOut(3000, function() { //third callback func
    photodisplay[3].fadeIn(3000);
    photodisplay[3].delay(3000).fadeOut(3000, function() { // fourth callback func
    photodisplay[4].fadeIn(3000);
    photodisplay[4].delay(3000).fadeOut(3000, function() {
    setTimeout(displayPhoto(), 3000);
    });
    }); 
    });
    }); 
    });

}// end of function displayPhoto


window.onload = preloadingPhotos;
```

}); //end ready

My url to get userid:

http://example.com/code.php?user_id=1

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are always setting the dirname instead of letting calling the function set it.  You could change:

```
function returnimages($dirname = "Photos/1") {
```

to

```
function returnimages($dirname) {
```

because otherwise the `$dirname` is always `Photo/1`.  Then, when you call the function, use:

```
returnimages('Photos/'.$user_id);
```

Comment: I still don't understand why putting the path in the function parameters didn't work. Isn't it the same? Confused. But it works! Do you have any idea how to call the array from php in javascript? :/

Comment: You're welcome.  The problem was that you were not putting a path in the function parameters.  You were basically setting the variable dirname ignoring whatever was set when the function was called.  If you want to put a php array in javascript, it depends how you are coding it.  Are you putting the php in the javascript of a completely javascript, html, or php page?

Comment: But shouldn't this work too? 
function returnimages($dirname = "Photos/" .$user_id) {
I'm setting the variable dirname to that but it changes depending on the userid? (sorry just don't understand, php is hard!)

Umm, I have a html page but it's now php because I have added php to it. And from this it calls an external javascript. So not sure what to do :S I am just getting different approaches from different sites and just getting confused :(

Comment: I know it looks like I haven't done much research or tried, but I have :( It's just really confusing. Not really near to finishing what I am intended to do but I am quite proud that I have something working ish :) but yeah, thank you again for just solving another milestone of mine :D:D

Comment: Yes, that function call would work too, but the main problem was actually declaring the function not calling it.  However, that way to write it is not as concise as it could be.

Comment: If the page is coded in php are you echoing the html code to make the javascript or setting a conditional php code to use a certain html code?  Basically: `<?php echo '<script>'; ?>` or `<?php if ($this) { ?><script><?php } ?>`

Comment: My page is coded in html, and php is just added in between <body> </body> and in the <head> I am added the script src for the external javascript file :S....

Comment: In that case, you can't fetch a php variable from the original html document to my knowledge unless you insert the javascript directly in the html document.

Comment: Do you reckon I could have your email so I can ask you more questions? :S if not, thank you so much for helping :)

Comment: Sorry, but I do not give out that information.  However, there are many people registered here able to answer questions and I am sure that if you ask another question if you have any doubts, they will be able to help you.  In addition, if you were satisfied with the answer, you may want to mark it as the chosen response by clicking the checkmark so that future visitors looking for a solution to a similar problem may find the answer fast and easily.

Comment: I'm just really confused... but thanks, I understand.

Oh nvm lol, couldn't mark it before, or maybe it was voting I couldn't do because I don't have enough points. lol done :)

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate in PHP by using the dot '.'. This will concatenate two string and then assign them to the variable $dirname. For example:

```
 $dirname = "Photos/" . $_GET['ID'];
```

The variable $dirname can then be placed in the function returnimages, like:

```
returnimages($dirname);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I just did this and it still doesn't work :S
I got this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')' in...... line 17
I'm a complete beginner to PHP, and would appreciate any help!

Comment: More information about your work can help us, how does the URL look like? What is the code surrounding the part that is troubling you? What did you already tried and what were the results?

Comment: I have just edited my question. Thank you! Hope it makes more sense to what I am trying to achieve? :S sorry for being so confusing and vague.

Comment: function have parameters, i.e., dosomething($var1) { }. You must provide the function with a value, this dosomething("Hello world"); When you define the function parameter as $var = "Hello world", you can call the function without providing a value for $var1, but a function with one parameter that is already been define is not function, but a part of the code. When you call the returnimages function you must provide input, this input is $dirname. This variable needs to be assigned a value, in your case $dirname = "Photos/" . $user_id;